# Veracode vulnerable Cryptographic issue

Tags: c#, veracode

I am facing cryptographic security issue which has noted by Veracode. Kindly check below and help me out from this.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider crypthandler =
    new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
```

Comment: Without more information added to the question it will probably be closed quickly. 1. What issue are you facing? 2. There needs to be a very good reason to use MD5, it has security issues. 3. What is the Veracode vulnerability, consider providing a link. 4.
What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd say the vulnerability IS using MD5. Try replacing it with some SHA2.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is considered an insecure or 'broken' hashing function. Assuming you're getting a CWE 327 (Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm) you can fix this by updating to the SHA-2 family of hash functions.

I would recommend SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512 for future proofing.

Example:

```
using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider crypthandler = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm (`CWE ID 327`)
Description
The use of a broken or risky cryptographic algorithm is an unnecessary risk that may result in the disclosure of
sensitive information.

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
SHA512CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider();
```

Ref below link:

http://bestanswers.in/2016/06/30/fix-veracode-flaw-cwe-id-327-use-broken-risky-cryptographic-algorithm/